# how to handle 400 errors using axios

Tags: php, laravel, axios

i have laravel project that use AXIOS code for store the data from url. however, the the url is broken or return error 400. the progress is stop...

how to i avoid error and the process still continue. i already use `throw error` code but still not work

here is my code

```
var url = 'https://www.imagephotolink.com';

axios.get(url, { responseType: "blob" }).then(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 200) {
       //catch and store process
    }else {
        throw new Error("Error");
    }
});
```

how do i avoid error 400 and still can continue the process

Answer (score 0):

You need to use catch for promises for managing errors. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

Your code should look something like this:

```js
var url = 'https://www.imagephotolink.com';

axios.get(url, { responseType: "blob" }).then(function (response) {
  //catch and store process
}).catch(function (response) {
  //handle errors like 400, 404, etc
});
```